# NSTableView save value without pressing Enter Key on lost focus

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview

[image: the below pic shows my app]

"First Number" is multiplied by "Second Number" to give "Sub-Total". Pressing "Total" button gives the sum of "Sub-Total"

As you can see in the image, the cell containing number "5" is in editable state. When i click the button "Total" a method is triggered which adds up the numbers in the "Sub-total" column. I want the numbers in editable state to be saved automatically before the addition is performed so that the correct answer would be 156.00 instead of 136.00 as seen in the label below the "Total" button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recall the MVC design pattern**

Your `NSTableView` is just a view, and you show the Model(Array) onto it.

So you changed the value in view part but your model is not changed. You need to change the model i.e, array or any collection that you are showing in the tableview.

In the button action just call `[tableView reloadData]`, Then the `- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`
: delegate method of tablview will get called and your model will get updated. Resulting in the your typed data.

Check the example:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.array=[NSMutableArray new];

        for (NSInteger i=0; i<30; i++) {
            [self.dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Obj %ld",i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",i]];
            self.array[i]=@(i);
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
    return self.array.count;
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    return self.array[row];
}


- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
    self.array[row]=object;

}
```

Your answer is here:

```
- (IBAction)button:(id)sender {

    [self.myTable reloadData];

    NSInteger row=[self.myTable selectedRow];
    NSLog(@"%@",[self.array objectAtIndex:row]);

}
```

Comment: I more thing, if you are saving total to the model this is not good, either you should calculate it after reading from the model. As saving total to the model is not good way, and it wasting memory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the cell (or, actually, the text field) that's being edited and when the "total" button is touched, call "resignFirstResponder" on that text field which should also update your subtotal and your array or array controller, which ultimately gives you the correct total.

One way to keep track of which cell is being edited is to set all of your editable cells' text fields to all use your view (or window) controller as a delegate and then you'll know which cell is being edited based on the delegate method [`control:textShouldBeginEditing:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSControlTextEditingDelegate/control%3atextShouldBeginEditing%3a) (the text field being edited is passed in via the "`control`" parameter... you can keep track of it in an ivar or property).  That's the same cell you can call "`resignFirstResponder`" on.